# Knockout: Catch exceptions in submit and click bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Rather than put non-DRY `try/catch` blocks in all my submit methods and click methods on my viewmodels just to display a messagebox and write to the console, I'd like a cross-cutting way to do just that.

Is it possible to overwrite the `click` and `submit` bindings with a wrapped version of their current impl that basically wraps the original call with a `try/catch`?

I tried this:

```
let defaultClickBindingHandler = (<any>ko.bindingHandlers).click;

(<any>ko.bindingHandlers).click = {
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        try {
            defaultClickBindingHandler.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        } catch (e) {
            shell.error(e);
        }
    },
    update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        try {
            defaultClickBindingHandler.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        } catch (e) {
            shell.error(e);
        }
    },
};
```

But I got the following error in the console:

```
Unable to process binding "click: function (){return refresh }"
Message: input.replace is not a function; 
View: [redacted]; 
ModuleId: [redacted]
```

Comment: Wow. Downvoted already? I wonder what was wrong with my question? Please tell me and I'll do my best to fix it - I'd love to get an answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want? You aren't providing any way to handle the thrown errors, it's kind of a "one size fits all" solution. Perhaps something like window.onError could be used to handle the "default" error handling case instead.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, seems like a valid question to me but we need some more information in order to reproduce the problem. Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: The window.onError is an interesting idea that I'll look into. I basically wanted to at least show an error in the UI, even if I can't actually handle it myself, because at the moment nothing happens except a console.log, which is invisible to the end user.

Comment: My `shell.error()` impl basically shows a Toastr popup with the error message.

Comment: Second @CrimsonChris: no idea about the downvote, interesting question, but a full / minimal repro would improve the question a lot.

Comment: PS. Have you considered DRYing out said logic in the view models? That's usually a more appropriate place for business logic.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like `window.onerror` could be what you need. However, if you do decide that you want to wrap the bindings instead it is possible. Please see [this jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ct6w99c/4) which shows how you might wrap the `click` binding.

I couldn't say for sure why your example code isn't working. One issue I can see is that you're trying to wrap both the `init` and `update` functions of the default binding. This isn't going to work as `click` and `submit` both only implement the `init` function. It's perfectly valid for a binding to only define one of these functions. The `css` binding for example only implements the `update` function.